# Column names with special characters (%, # etc)?

Tags: sql-server

I named one column name as `Attendance%` in few tables in a project and I'm getting Invalid column name error like below:

***Description***:

An  exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Code**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update previous_marks set previousclass=" + t2.Text + ",Attendance%=" + t3.Text + " where sid=" + t1.Text + "", cn)
```

**Error**

> Invalid column name 'Attendance'.

Comment: Yes, if they are [*Delimited (Quoted) Database Identifiers*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx). However, it would be best to *choose better column names* (especially since some interfaces/API doesn't correctly quote).

Comment: Help us help you. where is the stack trace? Can you please also post the query used in the web request. If your table is named `Attendance%`, use it in sql using `[]` or `""` like this `[Attendance%]` or this `"Attendance%"`

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update previous_marks set previousclass=" + t2.Text + ",Attendance%=" + t3.Text + " where sid=" + t1.Text + "", cn);

Comment: @DineshReddy That code is flawed: add Command Parameters to avoid SQL injection and "randomly broken queries". An Sql Command built from string concatenation is almost always 'wrong'.

Comment: In db table i create column name  as Attendance%, while passing that name in cmd,im getting that error commonly for multiple pages which using that table values,where i did mistake ?

Comment: @DineshReddy - Did you read my comment or the one posted by user2864740? the answer is in both the comments

Comment: now i got ,tq for your rply.

Comment: @DineshReddy Are words like `thank you` and `reply` too difficult to type in comparison to Attendance% and phone#?

Comment: Why not just stop using "lazy characters (%,#)" and just use "AttendancePercent" and "PhoneNumber"

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can create for example we need to put them with `quoted Identifier []`

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update previous_marks set previousclass=" + t2.Text + ",[Attendance%]=" + t3.Text + " where sid=" + t1.Text + "", cn)
```

Comment: Yeah you can, but why would you?  Doing so just opens the door for problems further down the track.  Picking better names is a more robust solution.  And don't concatenate SQL like that.

Comment: Not sure which bit you're commenting on but I stand by both my points.  I am not disagreeing with the facts of your answer but using non-standard column names may get you in trouble down the line when you start integrating with various libraries, reporting tools, systems.  

Concatenated SQL is never ok.

Comment: @LoztInSpace yes you are right  we should maintain standard for it.